# JavaScript: How to Rotate/Slideshow Text DIVs on page?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to modify the script below to slideshow/rotate through a handful of text DIVs.

I need these DIVs to appear in order: div 1, then div 2, then div 3. Each would appear for 5 seconds, then show the next div... but in order.

The script below works well for Random divs, but I need them to be in order: div 1, div 2, div 3... each time.

Code:

```
<div id="d1" style="display:none;">some text 1</div>
<div id="d2" style="display:none;">some text 2</div>
<div id="d3" style="display:none;">some text 3</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
divs = ['d1','d2','d3'];

function hideDivs() {
    for (var i=0; i<divs.length; i++)
    document.getElementById(divs[i]).style.display = 'none';
}

function showDiv() {
    hideDivs(); //hide them all before we show the next one.
    var randomDiv = divs[Math.floor(Math.random()*divs.length)];
    var div = document.getElementById(randomDiv).style.display = 'block';
    setTimeout(showDiv,500); //set a delay before showing the next div
}

showDiv();
</script>
```

I'm trying to rotate out 3 text-based DIV tags, one after the other.

- Div 1 should appear for 5 seconds...
- Then Div 2 should appear for 5 seconds...
- Then Div 3 should appear for 5 seconds...

The script I posted rotates out these DIV tags randomly. The script works, but I need to tweak it so it does what I need.

I need the script to show div 1, div 2, div 3-- in that order, not randomly.

I can't figure out how to do that.

Comment: Welcome to Webmasters. Questions of a coding nature are better suited to StackOverflow, but you have already asked the same question on SO. Please don't double post - if your question is deemed more suitable for another Stack Exchange site then it will be moved, as it is it is likely to simply get closed.